# Pull doesn't update current local branch on submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree

Everyday I go to the main repository of our project, run a pull, then travel 5 submodules in, to find my repository where I'm working.

Running a PULL on the parent downloads and sets the pointers to each commit on each submodule, but since I upload something many times a day and people upload stuff many times a day, I have to run a PULL and then start travelling down the pipe while checking-out the branch I was at on each of them (which stays the same, by the way) until I reach my repository, then commit, and PUSH.

That workflow is terrible. I'm wondering if there is any way I could make my repository to PULL and update the branches (or at least the current branch) , because I lose all checked out branches everytime I do that.

With artists, this is terrible, they keep uploading stuff to a detached head commit, because they have to be running pulls the same way and uploading all the way up.

Any ideas, setttings,h whatever?

I use Source Tree, but I can also use the console if needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+pull